# $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{\:x^3}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I apply L'Hopital thrice and I get 1/6 but here they've stopped at [infinity](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto0%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7Bx%7D-1%7D%7B%20x%5E%7B3%7D%7D%5Cright)).

What is the correct answer?

Comment: In this case you don't need l'Hopital at all. In case you want apply let verify if the form is indeterminate at each step you use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that L’Hopital rule is used only for limits of $\frac00$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form.

Right now, on substituting $x=0$, we get a $\frac00$ form. But, if we differentiate it once, we get: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x}{3x^2}$$ which is **not of** $\frac00$ form. So, we **cannot use L’Hopital rule** here.

Evaluating the above limit, the answer is obviously $\infty$.

Comment: If I get \frac{\infty }{0} do I apply L'Hopital?

Comment: @Husun No it is applicable **only** for the forms $\frac00$ and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. It is not applicable for any other forms such as $\frac{\infty}{0}, \frac10$, etc.

Comment: What do I do with the form \frac{\infty }{0} ?

Comment: Another question is $ \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{x^{-\frac{4}{3}}}{sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right) $
I'm get \frac{\infty }{0} when applying limit

Comment: its x to the power -4/3

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585391/lim-x-to-infty-left-fracx-frac43sin-left-frac1x-right here it is

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{e^x-1}{\:x^3}=\frac{e^x-1}{\:x}\frac1{x^2}\to1\cdot +\infty=+\infty$$

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the appreciation!

Answer (score 1):

using the rules of L'Hosptal one times we get
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x}{3x^2}=+\infty$$ you Can NOT use the rules one more times

Comment: "you Can use the rules one more times" How? Most probably a wrong suggestion.

Comment: no probably a TYPO

Comment: Obviously not a typo but the unfortunate propagation of a common mistake.

Comment: ok that is your opinion

Comment: As usual, one can wonder who can upvote such... *things*.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you used L’Hopital rule but look(assume I'm taking the limit all the time):

$$\frac{e^x-1}{x^3}=\frac{e^x}{3x^2}$$

This is a limit in the form of $\frac1{0}$, which in this case is determinate form, it goes to $+\infty$ because $\lim_{x\to0}x^2$  goes to $0$ from the positive direction

The answer is infinity

Comment: @samjoe I rewrote it to be more accurate, hope it makes it clearer